# handling multiple promises in aws Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to use lambda function to fetch hacker news stories using their API. The approach seems to work if I create this as regular Nodejs cron job but as a lambda function it just ends with success call without any output. Below is my code

```
const PromisePool = require("es6-promise-pool");
const rp = require("request-promise");

const getTopStories = async () => {
  let options = {
    method: "GET",
    uri: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    json: true
  };
    return rp(options).then(stories => {
      return (stories);
    })
    .catch(err => err);
}

const getStoryDetails = (storyId) => {
  let url = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/"+storyId+".json?print=pretty";
  let options = {
    method: "GET",
    uri: url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    json: true
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rp(options)
    .then(response => {
      if(response.type === "story"){
        resolve({
          story_id: response.id,
          pubDate: response.time,
          title: response.title,
          url: response.url,
          provider: "Hacker News",
          type: response.type,
          status: "NEW"
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}


let stories = [];

let promiseProducer = async (sList) => {
    stories = await sList.map(id => getStoryDetails(id));
    return stories;
}

exports.hknFeed = async (event) => {
    let idList = await getTopStories();
    console.log(idList);
    let pool = new PromisePool(promiseProducer(idList), 4);
    let poolPromise = pool.start();
    poolPromise.then(() => {
        Promise.all(stories).then(values => {
            console.log(values);
        })
    })
    return idList;
};
```

can someone point out what am I missing to get this working.

Note: getTopStories returns an array of 500 values, which causes too many requests to be fired and I assume it causes socket error somewhere. But if we limit the returning array to 10-15 values array, then the above code works and Promise.all resolves every promise and prints the value to console.

Comment: `promise.all` would take an array of promises, and I dont see `stories` being any populated with promises in it?, its just empty not sure i understand what this line is supposed to do `Promise.all(stories)...`.

Comment: Because return idList; is not waiting on the poolPromise to return. I'm not sure how you can use await and achieve Promise.all though, so I'm interested to see the answer

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://gist.github.com/indiesquidge/5960274889e17102b5130e8bd2ce9002

Comment: @jaya - variable stories is getting assigned in promiseProducer()

Comment: @NaguibIhab promisePool is getting promises in a batch of 4 from pool.start() (//promise limiter ) which I am using then to pass to Promise.all() to wait for all of them to finish and log the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
Apologies...seems like I was not paying attention. The above code is working  now in lambda function as my return statement was out of place. It should have been inside the Promise.all().then(()=>{return}). like below

```
const PromisePool = require("es6-promise-pool");
const rp = require("request-promise");

const getTopStories = async () => {
  let options = {
    method: "GET",
    uri: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    json: true
  };
    return rp(options).then(stories => {
      return (stories);
    })
    .catch(err => err);
}

const getStoryDetails = (storyId) => {
  let url = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/"+storyId+".json?print=pretty";
  let options = {
    method: "GET",
    uri: url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    json: true
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rp(options)
    .then(response => {
      if(response.type === "story"){
        resolve({
          story_id: response.id,
          pubDate: response.time,
          title: response.title,
          url: response.url,
          provider: "Hacker News",
          type: response.type,
          status: "NEW"
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}


let stories = [];

let promiseProducer = async (sList) => {
    stories = await sList.map(id => getStoryDetails(id));
    return stories;
}

exports.hknFeed = async (event) => {
    let idList = await getTopStories();
    console.log(idList);
    let pool = new PromisePool(promiseProducer(idList), 4);
    let poolPromise = pool.start();
    poolPromise.then(() => {
        Promise.all(stories).then(values => {
            console.log(values);
            return values;
        })
    })
};
```